# How to access Vaadin /frontend resources statically in spring boot application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin flow examples specify that styles should be placed in: /frontend/styles

This allows them to be importing in Vaadin views/components, but I need to access some of these files statically as well. What is the proper web url for accessing these style files? Or is this impossible?

The following URLs do not work:

- http://host/styles
- http://host/frontend/styles

I understand that /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources is also served statically, but I need to avoid having separate copies of the same file.

Edit:

The page I want to print is pure HTML. Rendered in a popup via JS:

```
var a = window.open('', '', 'height=1000, width=1500');
a.document.write('<html>...</html>');
```

The Html contains link tags to the css:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/print.css" />
```

Comment: This sounds like X/Y problem to me. Why you actually need to access them?

Comment: What kind of files are those? If you have them statically served from spring you could reference them (e.g. images directly, or css by injecting them in the bootstrap html, ...)

Comment: @TatuLund I have an independent piece of HTML rendered outside of the Vaadin context that needs to reference them. The independent HTML is used to render printable content because the Vaadin view cannot be printed directly.

Comment: Can we assume, that this is not _just_ a piece of HTML but also has JavaScript and other things in it?  Or why is it under `frontend` in the first place? For trivial HTML one would assume, that you would use `Html` inside Vaadin or even just an iframe to show the HTML created/served by some other means; in other words: if Vaadin hinders your progress, get it out of the loop.  To put a stop on further guesswork: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @cfrick It's just HTML, no JS. It's rendered via direct JS execution in a popup window. The popup itself is triggered by JS, but the contents are pure HTML. See my edit. I'll try to produce a more complete MRE, but Vaadin is not a hinderance from the client perspective. Only a hinderance in terms of exposing the css.

Comment: @cfrick The css is in the frontend folder because its *also* used by the application. The chunk of HTML is shown on vaadin pages, but cannot be printed directly from those pages due to the layout. I want to render the exact same HTML in a popup, style it the same, and then print it.

Comment: In your specific use case, where you don't want to bundle your files, but instead serve them as static files, you need to put them in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`. Vaadin uses that same directory for serving icons, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The files under the `/frontend` folder are bundled into the frontend bundle in production mode, they are not available as separate files; even though you might be able to access one in development mode, you shouldn't count on that behavior.